# Legacy API usage and event log

Tags: api, eventlogfile

Salesforce sent an email "because you're an admin of an org that is actively using the legacy API endpoints". While this mentions only version 7.0 through 20.0 I only found version 27.0 in the logs which will be retired at a later date.

Either way - the log file doesn't make any sense. I downloaded it as described in this help article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000351312&type=1

The SOQL is:

```
SELECT LogFile, EventType, CreatedDate FROM EventLogFile WHERE EventType IN ('API', 'RestApi', 'ApiTotalUsage')
```

So - first of all, I don't understand why I only have entries for `ApiTotalUsage` - as we are actively using the REST API - but okay. All the entries are from one user that is used for all kinds of integrations which makes it hard to pinpoint the exact source. The client name is missing and IP addresses are all over the place. One really interesting fact is that the connected app id is `888U00000004CPV` and the `888` prefix already looks pretty fishy.

Looking at the connected apps I can confirm that the id does not match any of the apps in this list let alone having a similar id:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM ConnectedApplication
```

Since there's no client name but an (albeit very weird) connected app, I guess that it is somehow tied to some connected app activity I can't nail down just yet. Does anybody have any kind of suggestion whatsoever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I came to a dead end on this one. I believe you're going to need to get Support involved. Here's what I found out.

The key prefix `888` is for an object called `OauthConsumer`, with the label `Remote Access`. This object cannot be interacted with as a system administrator. Attempts to describe or query the object in any API I tried returns the usual "sObject type 'OauthConsumer' is not supported" error (note proper title-case, so it is indeed a restricted object).

If you try to use the key prefix as a URL, `/888`, you'll be taken to the URL: `/identity/app/RemoteAccessRedirectPage.apexp?retURL=%2F02u`, which tells you that it's been moved to Applications. You'll be redirected to Setup > Create > Applications in Classic mode (`/02u`). None of the records I see here have that key prefix...

You can *try* using `/888U00000004CPV` as the URL, it may redirect you to the correct Application, or you may just get some sort of weird `Data Not Available` type error. If it gets you where you need to be, great.

As for the former part, what that help topic does't tell you is [that](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro):

> Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance Edition organizations have free access to the insecure external assets, login, logout, and total API usage event log files with 1-day data retention. For an extra cost, you can access all log file types with 30-day data retention.

You don't get the logs you need unless you pay for it. That said, you can probably request temporary access to this feature so you can get the data you need.

Comment: Likewise, the [API Total Usage doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_apitotalusage.htm#:~:text=Call%2DOptions%20header.-,CONNECTED_APP_ID,-Type) says to contact Salesforce if the CONNECTED_APP_ID uses prefix 888

Comment: @KrisGoncalves nice. Didn't realize that existed. I'll edit it in when I'm not mobile.

Comment: That is all really really helpful. I amended the additional information in the case details. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Turns out this is an entry under `Connected Apps OAuth Usage` - in my case it is Zapier. But it seems there's no way to find out to which entry the id belongs besides contacting Salesforce Support.

Comment: @Semmel Eventually did you have to perform any active work to make sure that the connected app comply with a non legacy API version? or did they eventually update it?

Comment: @ShlomiUziel It's still ongoing. No changes from Zapier and no proactive solutions from our side (not my responsibility). I'll update this as soon as I get any new information.